# Is there a way to add to a global variable?

Tags: python

I am trying to create hangman in Python. I have two variables I'm having trouble with; "revealed" and "max_guess". What I want to do is have the player input a letter, add guessed letter to a list, and have a function check if any letter of the word selected by the computer is in the list of guessed letters.

That function then has a for let in word with an if statement nested in it. The if statement's condition is if let is in guessed letters, it will add that letter to the string 'revealed'. Otherwise, it will increase the max_guess by 1, and add an underscore to the revealed string. Once the max_guess reaches six, the hangman game will end.

For both variables, the error message says that the local variable of max_guess and revealed are referenced before assignment, even though I defined both of those variables outside of a function and I am simply adding to it.

```
   guessed_letters = []
   revealed = ""
def is_in_word(guess):
  """Checks if guessed letter is in chosen word"""
  for let in word:
    if let in guessed_letters: 
      revealed += "let"
    else: 
      revealed += '_'
      max_guess += 1
      print(max_guess)
  return revealed
```

I want the code to show the letters in the word the player has guessed, and +1 to every wrong guess.

Comment: You have to declare `max_guess = 0` inside `is_in_word()` function before you use it.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your function you can declare

```
global guessed_letters
```

In this case though, since you're only reading the var, probably better just to pass it in:

```
def is_in_word(guess, guessed_letters):
```

Comment: I am now getting invalid syntax for the second part of my code.

Comment: "second part"? Can you be more specific - the stack trace should show you exactly what is invalid ... BTW, adding "let" to a string will add the literal string "let". Lose the quotes to add the actual letter held in the var let.

Answer (score 0):

Your variables are uninitiated in your function. You have to declare `max_guessed` outside of the loop as something before you do `max_guessed += 1` like max_guessed = 0;

Comment: Yea I saw that after my page refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here:

```
var = 0

def function():
    var = 1
    print("inside the function", var)

function()
print("outside the function", var)
```

Output:

```
inside the function 1
outside the function 0
```

My guess is that this isn't the output you're expecting. Here's the thing: When you attempt to modify a global variable inside a function, (or any variable that isn't bound to the scope of the function), you actually cannot modify it. The snippet I posted looks like it's modifying `var`, which is in the global scope, by setting it to 1. However, what's really happening is a local variable with the same name is created and set to 1.

If you want the function to be able modify your global variable(s), you will have to indicate this with the `global` keyword:

```
var = 0

def function():
    global var
    var = 1
    print("inside the function", var)

function()
print("outside the function", var)
```

Output:

```
inside the function 1
outside the function 1
```

Comment: Even when I create the variable in the function or make it global it returns invalid syntax

Comment: It's impossible for me to help you unless you tell me exactly on which line the syntax error is occurring.